# error when install pygame using -m pip install pygame from cmd

Tags: python, pygame

```
C:\Windows\System32>python -m pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]
....

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

i try using `pip3 install pygame --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures` but it still error
I'm new to python so I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install/update setuptools:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

It will most probably fix your issue.

Comment: No, this won't fix the issue unless they got a C compiler to compile pygame from source